# AES: Не дешифруется строка

Tags: java, android, шифрование, aes

У меня есть две функции, `encrypt` и `decrypt`. В `encrypt` я создаю ключ, шифрую строку и добавляю в начало строки сам ключ. В `decrypt` сначала отделяю ключ от зашифрованной строки(размер ключа фиксированный) и пытаюсь расшифровать, при этом результат не совпадает с начальной строкой, что и является проблемой.

Проверил в дебаге, массив `key` при вызове `decrypt(encrypt(string))` в обеих функциях одинаковый, видимо проблема в `SecretKeySpec`(имхо).

Как можно исправить?

Сам код:

```
static String encrypt(String str) {
    SecretKeySpec sks = null;
    byte[] key = null;
    try {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed("this is seed".getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128, sr);
        key = kg.generateKey().getEncoded();
        sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Crypto", "AES secret key spec error");
    }

    // Encode the original data with AES
    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        encodedBytes = c.doFinal(str.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Crypto", "AES encryption error");
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(key, Base64.DEFAULT) + 
        Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

static String decrypt(String str) {

    byte[] key = Base64.decode(str.substring(0, 25), Base64.DEFAULT);

    byte[] strBytes =
        Base64.decode(str.substring(25, str.length()), Base64.DEFAULT);

    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    // Decode the encoded data with AES
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(strBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Crypto", "AES decryption error");
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(decodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

**UPD** Вызов методов:

```
editText.setText(Crypt.encrypt(editText.getText().toString()));
...
editText.setText(Crypt.decrypt(editText.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: `видимо проблема в SecretKeySpec(имхо)` – если Вы выведите хэш-коды `sks`, то увидите, что они совпадают (случай коллизий опустим). Более того, если Вы посмотрите на содержимое шифруемой и расшифрованной строк в байтовом представлении, то увидите, что они тоже совпадают. Проблема локализована – она заключается в последней строке метода `decrypt()`. В ответах уже написали что именно неверно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас в не в ключе, а в лишнем кодировании при возврате строки.

Проще всего такой код отлаживать на JVM при помощи тестов.

```
// этот тест для обычного JUnit
// я не пробовал запускать его на андроиде
@Test
public void encrypt() throws Exception {
    String cryptoText = AES.encrypt("test");
    String plainText = AES.decrypt(cryptoText);
    assertThat(plainText, is("test"));
}

static String encrypt(String str) {
    SecretKeySpec sks = null;
    byte[] key = null;
    try {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed("this is seed".getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128, sr);
        key = kg.generateKey().getEncoded();
        sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Crypto", "AES secret key spec error");
    }

    // Encode the original data with AES
    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        encodedBytes = c.doFinal(str.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Crypto", "AES encryption error");
    }
    // я добавил длину ключа и разделитель
    String encodeKey = Base64.encodeToString(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodeKey.length() + "$" + encodeKey +
        Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);        
}

static String decrypt(String str) {

    int pos = str.indexOf("$");
    int keyLength = Integer.valueOf(str.substring(0, pos));
    int keyStart = pos + 1;

    byte[] key = Base64.decode(str.substring(keyStart, keyStart + keyLength), Base64.DEFAULT);

    int dataStart = keyStart + keyLength;
    byte[] strBytes =
        Base64.decode(str.substring(dataStart, str.length()), Base64.DEFAULT);

    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    // Decode the encoded data with AES
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(strBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Crypto", "AES decryption error");
    }

    // Base64 не надо, так как у вас там просто строка
    // return Base64.encodeToString(decodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return new String(decodedBytes);
}
```

Comment: Тест не запускается - выдаёт `encodeToString in android.util.Base64 not mocked`.

Comment: @Evgeniy Тест написан для JVM. Для запуска мне пришлось немного модифицировать сам код, так как на JVM Base64 имеет иной интерфейс.

Comment: `Проблема у вас в не в ключе, а в том как вы его достаете из зашифрованного текста.` Поменял в коде только последнюю строку метода `decrypt` и всё заработало как надо, так что думаю первую проблему можно обнулить :)

Comment: возможно это из-за разницы в реализации Base64 на JVM и на андроид.