# Шифрование текста в Java

Tags: java, android, криптография, шифрование, aes

Для шифрования и расшифровки текста использовал код, найденный в интернете:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;
public static byte[] crypt(int mode, byte[] value, String secret) throws Exception {
    byte[] key = secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    key = sha.digest(key);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(mode, secretKey);

    return cipher.doFinal(value);
}
```

Для шифрования:

```
qwe = new String(crypt(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (Текст).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ключ));
```

Для расшифровки:

```
qwe1 = new String(crypt(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, зашифрованный_текст_Типа_byte[], ключ), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Ключ пользователь вводит любой. Шифрование полностью работает. Но при расшифровке возникла проблемма.

Зашифрованный текст записывается в переменную типа `string`, а требуется `byte[]`. Конвертировать `string` в `byte[]` у меня не получилось, также как и из поля ввода текста зашифрованный текст передавать в `byte[]`.

Что тут можно сделать?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-byte-array

Comment: [возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621938/178576)

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае можно сделать так

```
qwe = new String(crypt(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (Текст).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ключ));
```

Для расшифровки:

```
qwe1 = new String(crypt(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, qwe.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ключ), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: А я могу что нибудь сделать, что в зашифрованном тексте не было иероглифов, типа таких ��J^ݜ5~�.৚�v

Comment: А зачем? Его никто читать не собирается, и смысла в этом большого нет

Comment: Просто у меня расшифрование, так и  не заработало.

Comment: Просто смысл программы (платформа Android) в том, что пользователь вводит текст, ключ и получает зашифрованый текст. Потом этот зашифрованный текст копирует, вставляет в другое поле, вводит ключ и получает расшифрованный текст. Я сделал шифрование, но расшифровать скопированные и вставленные иероглифы не получается

Comment: Можно дополнительно кодировать эти иероглифы в BASE64, HEX или любую другую кодировку, переводящую бинарные данные в печатные символы - тогда проблем с копипастом не будет.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {

    private static final String key = "aesEncryptionKey";
    private static final String initVector = "encryptionIntVec";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String originalString = "password";
        System.out.println("Original String to encrypt - " + originalString);
        String encryptedString = encrypt(originalString);
        System.out.println("Encrypted String - " + encryptedString);
        String decryptedString = decrypt(encryptedString);
        System.out.println("After decryption - " + decryptedString);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted));

            return new String(original);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]